# Click link and call javascript and then "Open in new tab"

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onclick

I have a link in my page.

```
<a onclick="Click()">Click me</a>
```

When I click this link, fires onclick event that call Click function. In this function, I have some javascript code and then, I want to redirect to another page.

```
function Click() { 
    //some code
    window.location = url;
}
```

When user right click on link and select "Open in new tab", new tab opens, and url is: "about:blank".

How to I correct this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is not to replace anchor functionality with Javascript. Anchors are designed to take you to a new URL. If you have an anchor, use it as an anchor (eg, set a `href` on it). Don't bind a click event that uses `window.location` to redirect to a new url.

Your current anchor has no `href`. So when you try and open it in a new tab, there's no surprise that nothing loads. You're literally opening nothing in the new tab.

If you *really* need to set the URL dynamically, then change the href of the element using javascript. For example:

```
document.getElementById('my-element').href = new_href;
```

It goes without saying that this needs to be done before the anchor is clicked (not on click). For example, on `window.load`, or the completion of the function that generates the dynamic URL.

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.open` function and pass `_blank` in second argument function

```
  function Click() { 
    //some code
    window.open(url,'_blank');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should correct your anchor tag to be something like this:

```
   <a href="http://yourLink.com" target="_blank" onclick="Click();">link text</a>
```

this way when user click on the link it'll open in new tab and you'll execute the Click function.